# Nokogiri: Get text which is not inside the <a> tag

Tags: nokogiri

Take a look at this example:

```
<li><a href="http://website.com/">This is a website</a>, it belongs to John Sulliva</li>
```

I can get the content of the `<li>` tag by using:

```
nodeset = doc.css('li')
```

I also can get the text inside the `<a>` tag by using:

```
nodeset.each do |element|

  ahref = element.css('a') // <-- <a href="http://website.com/">This is a website</a>
  name = ahref.text.strip // <--This is a website
end
```

But how do I get the rest of the text within the `<li>` tag but without the text from the `<a>` tag?

From this example, I like to get

> ", it belongs to John Sullivan"

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is straightforward using XPath and the `text()` node test. If you have extracted the `li`s into `nodeset`, you can get the text with:

```ruby
nodeset.xpath('./text()')
```

Or you can get it directly from the whole doc:

```ruby
doc.xpath('//li/text()')
```

This uses the `text()` node test as part of te XPath expression, not the `text` Ruby method. It extracts any text nodes that are *direct* descendants of the `li` node, so doesn’t include the contents of the `a` element.

Answer (score 0):

I found a cheap way to get the rest of the text:

```
  ahref = element.css('a')

  name = ahref.text.strip

  suppl =  element.text.strip.gsub(name, '')
```